# import python modules in init file

Tags: python, init, python-module

I have python scripts in a structure like this:

```
Folder:
    -main.py
    SubFolder:
        -file1.py
        -file2.py
        -filen.py
        -__init__.py
```

file1 has a module lets call it "module1()" and a variable "variable1".

file2 has "module2()" and "variable2" etc

So far, and it works perfectly, I used this way:

in main:

```
from subFolder import file1, file2
file1.module1()
file2.module2(file1.variable1)

file1.variable1
```

But since there are many files in the subFolder, I would like to make it more clean and elegant.
I tried writing in the **init**.py file this

```
from file1 import module1
from file2 import module2
etc
```

And then in the main:

```
 import subFolder as sf
 sf.module1()
 sf.module2(sf.variable1)  <--
```

which seems to work correctly for the modules, but not for the variables(indicated by the arrow).
What should I do? Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to import it explicitly but since you mentioned that you have a lot of modules in your [package](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/111882) “SubFolder” I will suggest you utilize [*dunder*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DunderAlias) [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)
So you could type:

```
from subFolder import *
```

And it will import everything that you will specify in `__all__` inside your `__init__.py`.

See answer by @alec-thomas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64130/7598113) for more details and examples.

**Pros:**

- No need to specify every module, function or variable explicitly.
- One import bring you everything you need.

**Cons:**

- You will have to remember to update `__all__` every time you add, rename or delete stuff in your sub-modules.
- Over time once you a have a lot of sub-modules it becomes unclear what exactly will be imported.